# Adjusting spacing of one row in LineLegend?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

**Background**

I have the following plot:

```
    Plot[Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0.000001, 0.999}, 
  ImageSize -> Automatic -> Medium, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}, 
  FrameLabel -> {None, None, 
    LineLegend[{RGBColor[25/255, 101/255, 176/255], Gray, Black, 
      RGBColor[136/255, 204/255, 238/255], 
      RGBColor[181/255, 143/255, 194/255]}, {Style["Q = test1", Black,
        FontSize -> 20], Style["Q = test3", Black, FontSize -> 20], 
      Style["Q = test4", Black, FontSize -> 20], 
      Style["Q = test5", Black, FontSize -> 20], 
      Style["Q = test2", Black, FontSize -> 20]}, 
     LegendMarkers -> {{"\[EmptySquare]", 20}, {"\[FilledSquare]", 
        20}, {"\[FilledCircle]", 20}, {"\[FilledUpTriangle]", 
        20}, {"\[EmptyUpTriangle]", 20}}, 
     LegendLayout -> {"Row", 2}]}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Prepend[ticks2[1/10, 1], {0, 0}], 
     None}, {ticks[0.2, 1], None}}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 15]]
```

**Question**
Is it possible to move the Q values in the second row of the legend so that they are centered below the spaces between the Q values in the first row? More generally, how can one center the second row of legend elements below the the top row elements?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
colors = {RGBColor[25/255, 101/255, 176/255], Gray, Black, 
   RGBColor[136/255, 204/255, 238/255], 
   RGBColor[181/255, 143/255, 194/255]};

labels = {Style["Q = test1", Black, FontSize -> 20], 
   Style["Q = test3", Black, FontSize -> 20], 
   Style["Q = test4", Black, FontSize -> 20], 
   Style["Q = test5", Black, FontSize -> 20], 
   Style["Q = test2", Black, FontSize -> 20]};

markers = {{"□", 20}, {"■", 20}, {"●", 20}, {"▲", 20}, {"△", 20}};

legend0 = LineLegend[colors, labels, 
  LegendMarkers -> markers, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 2}]
```

[image]

#### 1. Post-process `LineLegend` output to modify alignments:

```
alignLegendColumns = RawBoxes @
    Replace[ToBoxes[#], {HoldPattern["Columns" -> a_] :> 
        Rule["Columns", a /. Left -> Center], 
      HoldPattern[GridBoxDividers -> _] -> Rule[GridBoxDividers, False]}, All] &;

legend1 = alignLegendColumns @ legend0
```

[image]

```
Plot[Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0.000001, 0.999}, 
 ImageSize -> Automatic -> Medium, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {None, None, legend1}]
```

[image]

#### 2. Use a custom layout function:

A custom layout function that takes the number of columns (`ncols`) and, optionally, legend spacings (`{spacingBetweenMarkerAndLabel, spacingBetweenLegends})`, and row spacings as arguments:

```
ClearAll[legendLayout]
legendLayout[ncols_, legendspacings_ : Automatic, rowspacings_ : 1] := 
  Column[Row[Row[#, 
    Spacer[First[#, #] &[legendspacings /. Automatic -> {2, 5}]]] & /@ #, 
    Spacer[Last[#, #] &[legendspacings /. Automatic -> {2, 5}]]] & /@ 
     Partition[#, ncols, ncols, 1, {}], Alignment -> Center, 
    Spacings -> rowspacings] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
LineLegend[colors, labels, LegendMarkers -> markers, 
  LegendLayout -> legendLayout[3]]
```

[image]

Use `legendLayout[2]` above to get

[image]

Use `legendLayout[4]` to get

[image]

Use `legendLayout[2, Automatic, 0]` to get

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

As a workaround, put the first row in [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) and leave the second row in the [`FrameLabel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameLabel.html)

```
Plot[Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0.000001, 0.999},
 ImageSize -> Medium,
 PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed},
 PlotRange -> {0, 1},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {None, None,
   LineLegend[
    {RGBColor[136/255, 204/255, 238/255],
     RGBColor[181/255, 143/255, 194/255]},
    (Style[#, Black, FontSize -> 20] & /@
      {"Q = test5", "Q = test2  "}),
    LegendMarkers -> {{"▲", 20}, {"△", 20}},
    LegendLayout -> "Row"]},
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 15],
 PlotLegends ->
  Placed[
   LineLegend[
    {RGBColor[25/255, 101/255, 176/255], Gray, Black},
    (Style[#, Black, FontSize -> 20] & /@
      {"Q = test1", "Q = test3", "Q = test4"}),
    LegendMarkers -> {{"□", 20}, {"■", 
       20}, {"●", 20}}],
   Above]]
```

[image]